# How to use ProGuard with OrmLite in android

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, ormlite

I'm using OrmLite 4.48 in my Android project.
I added these lines to my proguard.cfg file:

```
-dontnote
-libraryjars libs/ormlite-android-4.48.jar
-libraryjars libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar


-keepattributes Signature
-keep class ir.hnfadak.simineh.database.** { *; }

-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
} 

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

but when I want to get signed APK I got these warnings:

> ProGuard: [Simineh] Warning:
>   com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.JellyBeanApiCompatibility: can't find
>   referenced method 'android.database.Cursor
>   rawQuery(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],android.os.CancellationSignal)'
>   in class android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
>   ProGuard: [Simineh] Warning:
>   com.j256.ormlite.android.compat.JellyBeanApiCompatibility$JellyBeanCancellationHook:
>   can't find referenced class android.os.CancellationSignal

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the below line solved my problem

```
-ignorewarnings
```

:D